# How to show a group of 3 elements of a collection using JSTL in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a list of n elements that I want to output in a group of 3. The size of the collection can vary a lot, but the output must be grouped in 3.

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <div>element 1</div>
      <div>element 2</div>
      <div>element 3</div>
   </li>

   <li>
      <div>element 4</div>
      <div>element 5</div>
      <div>element 6</div>
   </li>

   <li>
      <div>element 7</div>
      <div>element 8</div>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

I would like to use a forEach and a if statement, but I cannot get the output to generate properly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the syntax, but this should help, using the "count" property of "varStatus" to know what element number you are on...

EDIT: Apparently ".count" is NOT zero indexed, so the correct code would be:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

...
<c:set var="myListSize" value="${fn:length(myList)}"/>

        <c:forEach var="element" items="${myList}" varStatus="stat">

            <c:choose>

                <c:when test="${ stat.count == 1 }">
                   <ul>
                   <li>
                      <div>${element}</div>
                </c:when>

                <c:when test="${ stat.count == myListSize }">
                      <div>${element}</div>
                   </li>
                   </ul>
                </c:when>

                <c:when test="${stat.count % 3 == 0 && stat.count < myListSize }">
                      <div>${element}</div>
                   </li>
                   <br/>
                   <li>
                </c:when>

                <c:otherwise>
                      <div>${element}</div>
                </c:otherwise>

            </c:choose>

        </c:forEach>
```

It can still be improved, but for now it works.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be optimal, but how about just doing one pass in Java scriptlet, creating groups of 3s, adding them to a bean, and then iterating over those with 2 nested foreach loops.